# Difference in creating a Spring/Hibernate/Maven project in Eclipse and through Command Line

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven

What is the difference in creating a Spring/Hibernate/Maven project in Eclipse using New > Project > Maven > Maven Project, and through Command Line using mvn archetype:generate?

Thanks

Comment: One creates an Eclipse project, the other doesn't.

Comment: `mvn ecplise:eclipse` converts it to an eclipse project.